# Error message when booting Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, acpi

I am getting a black screen with this error message when booting Ubuntu 18.04:

[image]

The system runs well, except it's not detecting USB ports via VirtualBox. Could this be the reason?

VirtualBox 6.0 is installed with the corresponding Extension Pack.

Answer (score 0):

This means only one: there is a bug in your BIOS ACPI. Say thanks to your machihe's OEM. And the only thing you can do/try is to update BIOS/UEFI to the latest version from OEM's support page. But also there is no any warranty it is fixed in most recent version of BIOS/UEFI. Most often it is not. But you should try.
P.S. And this is not related to your VB issues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You know, I didn't have this problem when, I was using 18.10. It started right after uninstalling 18.10 and installing 18.04.

Comment: They have different kernels and different kernels may output different messages on the same hardware. It is possible in 18.10 added some workaround to this issue.